# Error SAGA algorithms in Modeller QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS Modeller and I try to use SAGA algorithms but it doesn't work. GRASS algorithms work just fine but SAGA doesn't.
I am not sure if I have to configurate something.

What is worng?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I get this message:        Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
SUM6: C:\Users\Lia\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\b3c7373ccee64b06a0f1253bc7a5ee60\outfileALG0.tif

The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected

Comment: Does SAGA work without the Modeler? Like Polygon centroid on a simple polygon shapefile layer?

Comment: Yes. I tried the same algorithm without the Modeler and it works. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: I have not yet worked with the Modeller. If noone here has an idea, you can report the bug at https://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues

Comment: I report the bug but I didn't get an answer yet. I found that just some SAGA algorithms doesn'te work: Grids Sum, Raster Calculator ans Grids Product. Does anyone have idea why?